# Again about pressing Home button and resuming from last activity

Tags: android

I saw a lot of topics, but no normal solution to my problem.
I have 2 activities A and B. The sequence is: A->B->Home->Launch again->A
In documentation it's said that whole stack will go to foreground. And it actually goes, but it also launches A again, so the stack now is: A B A.
I tried to make A "singleTask" hoping that when I press the button system will find A already running and my stack will appear on the screen. And system finds my A, but now it clear the stack and it look like: A.
I ran out of ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by running app using Intellij IDEA. When I run it manually, stack works as expected.